# SharePoint 2010, Powershell - Loop through all Document Libraries, create view and set it as default

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, scripting

I'm having a little trouble with a script I'm working on for SharePoint 2010. I'm only a beginner with Powershell so haven't been able to to spot the no doubt obvious and glaring problem.

The desire for the script is to loop through each web-site in each site collection, create a view for Document Libraries only and set that view as default.

**Issue 1)** Currently it appears to enumerate the Document Libraries but then creates the view multiple times in the first library it found. Something is wrong with the foreach loops but I don't know what.

**Issue 2)** I need to integrate this section so I can set the view as default but I'm not too sure where to stick it so it loops through with the changes to each library.

```
$site= New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite $siteURL
$web=$site.OpenWeb()
$list=$web.Lists["$list"]
$view=$list.Views["Detailed"]
$view.DefaultView = $true
$view.Update()
$list.Update()
```

Any assistance on these two issues would be of great help:-). Thanks, Ashley

**Full Script:**

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -erroraction SilentlyContinue
$siteURL = "http://sp14fdev01/"
$site = Get-SPSite($siteURL)

foreach($web in $site.AllWebs) {
foreach($list in $web.Lists) {
        if($list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary") {

 $site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($SiteURL) ;
 $web = $site.OpenWeb($SiteURL);
 $list = $web.Lists.item($listname);

 $viewfields = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection 
 $viewfields.Add("DocIcon") 
 $viewfields.Add("LinkFilename") 
 $viewfields.Add("_UIVersionString") 
 $viewfields.Add("FileSizeDisplay") 
 $viewfields.Add("Created") 
 $viewfields.Add("Modified") 
 $viewfields.Add("Editor") 
 [void]$list.Views.Add("Detailed", $viewfields, "", 100, $true, $true)

 $list.Update();
 }}
 $web.Dispose();
 $site.Dispose();
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The changes are explained in the comments.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -erroraction SilentlyContinue

$siteURL = "http://sp14fdev01/"
$site = Get-SPSite($siteURL)

foreach($web in $site.AllWebs) {
  foreach($list in $web.Lists) {
    if($list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary") {
// the variables `$web` and `$list` already reference the objects you need
      //$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($SiteURL) ;
      //$web = $site.OpenWeb($SiteURL);

// new instance of the list is necessary to avoid the error "Collection was modified"
      $newList = $web.Lists.item($list.ID);

      $viewfields = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection 
      $viewfields.Add("DocIcon") 
      $viewfields.Add("LinkFilename") 
      $viewfields.Add("_UIVersionString") 
      $viewfields.Add("FileSizeDisplay") 
      $viewfields.Add("Created") 
      $viewfields.Add("Modified") 
      $viewfields.Add("Editor") 
      [void]$newList.Views.Add("Detailed", $viewfields, "", 100, $true, $true)

      $newList.Update();

// setting the default view
      $view=$newList.Views["Detailed"]
      $view.DefaultView = $true
      $view.Update()
    }
  }

  $web.Dispose();
}

$site.Dispose();
```

Comment: Hi Marek, Thanks for the quick response. I'll test it out and report back.

Comment: Hi Marek, It looks like an unrelated issue in the script but is loop through and fails with this error -

0
1
2
3
4
5
6
An error occurred while enumerating through a
 collection: Collection was modified; enumera
tion operation may not execute..
At C:\Users\quickdev1\Documents\LoopThroughAl
lLibrariesCreateView.ps1:6 char:8
+ foreach <<<< ($list in $web.Lists) {
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperati 
   on: (Microsoft.Share...on+SPEnumerator:S  
  PEnumerator) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadEnumeration

Comment: It is related - I forgot one should not modify the elements of the the collection that is being enumerated. Try the updated script I posted.

Comment: Hi Marek, It still seems to have the same behaviour with that error.
An error occurred while enumerating through a
 collection: Collection was modified; enumera
tion operation may not execute..
I'll see if I can track down the cause. Thanks for your help so far.
At C:\Users\quickdev1\Documents\LoopThroughAl
lLibrariesCreateView.ps1:7 char:10
+   foreach <<<< ($list in $web.Lists) {
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperati 
   on: (Microsoft.Share...on+SPEnumerator:S  
  PEnumerator) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadEnumeration

Comment: **ENUMERATION ERROR** This enumeration issue occurs for any array object being updated while enumerated in a ForEach loop. Its a simple fix, instead of a ForEach($list in $AllLists){} just use `$AllLists = $web.Lists; for($i=0; $i -lt $AllLists.Count; $i++){  $list = $AllLists[$i]; ....... }`
**GETTING DOCUMENT LIBRARIES** `$AllLists = $web.GetListOfType([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBaseType]::DocumentLibrary)`